# What value? to get the lowest price for the entire period?

Tags: pine-script

lowest(close,B) <- in this case ,how do i set whole time lowest price?

What value should be entered in the period variable to get the lowest price for the entire period?

Comment: Do you still need help on this question?

Answer (score 0):

`lowest(close, bar_index)` - the minimum value for all the available bars